# A linear operator always has a cyclic vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that given a linear operator $f$ on $\Bbb{K}^2$, where $\Bbb{K}$ is a field, any non-zero non-eigenvector is a cyclic vector for $f$. Then I'm asked to show show that $f$ either has a cyclic vector or it is a scalar multiple of $I _2$.

Here's what I did for the first part: Since we know $\dim(\Bbb{K}^2)=2$ it suffices to find a linearly independant set with cardinality $2$. Now, let $\mathbf{v}$ be a non-zero vector which is not a characteristic value of $f$ then $f(\mathbf{v})\neq\alpha \mathbf{v}$. This shows that $f(\mathbf{v})\notin <\mathbf{v}>$ hence $\{\mathbf{v},f(\mathbf{v})\}$ is LI.

I don't know what to do in the second part, however I'm guessing that the scalar will be the eigenvalue but what if all the vectors that make $f$ are zero or a zero and an eigenvector( That can't happen right?)

Out of curiosity, this does not hold in $\Bbb{K}^n$ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ doesn't have a cyclic vector then by what you have already shown we know that every non-zero vector is an eigenvector.  There are two cases:

1. Every non-zero vector is an eigenvector for the *same* eigenvalue $\alpha$.  In this case show that $T = \alpha I$
2. There are non-zero eigenvectors $v$ and $w$, with eigenvalues $\alpha$ and $\beta$, such that $\alpha \neq \beta$.  In this case show that $v + w$ is not an eigenvector, contradicting your assumption.

P.s. The general statement for $\mathbb K^n$ is as follows.  If $\mathbb K$ is algebraically closed then $T\colon\mathbb K^n \to \mathbb K^n$ has a cyclic vector if and only if the minimum polynomial and characteristic polynomial of $T$ are equal.

There are plenty of maps whose minimum and characteristic polynomials are not equal which are not of the form $\alpha I$, so when $n > 2$ the answer is no, it's not true that every $T$ either has a cyclic vector or is of the form $\alpha I$.

Comment: I don't understand "If $f$ doesn't have an eigenvalue then every non-zero vector is an eigenvector". Seems to me that if a linear operator doesn't have an eigenvalue then it doesn't have any eigenvectors, either.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you beat me to it.

Comment: Oops, I meant if $f$ doesn't have a cyclic vector.  I've fixed it.

Comment: @Jim do you by chance know a site which hosts a proof of the last statement so I could read it later when I learn more about field extensions?

Comment: I don't know of a source, when the time comes you could probably prove it yourself without too much effort.